# Flask application running in a Docker Container unable to access MSSQL Database

Tags: python, linux, docker

I am trying to run a Flask application running off Linux in a Docker container. When I try logging into the website, I get the below error message as my user is not found in the MSSQL database, even though the user exists:

**sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")**

When I run the Flask application locally on my Windows computer and I try logging into the website, my user is found in the MSSQL database, and I am able to login to the website successfully. My connection string is set to 'Trusted Connection = Yes'. Below is my working connection string on my local Windows environment:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={quote_plus(os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI','Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:****.database.windows.net,1433;Database=****;Trusted_Connection=yes;'))}"
```

Since 'Trusted Connection' is only used for Windows authentication and not Linux, I tried removing 'Trusted_Connection=yes' from the connection string, but now we get the above **Login failed for user ' '** error.

Below is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80 80
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["run.py"]
```

Can anyone provide insight as to how I can get this connection string to work in a Linux environment? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not developed applications with flask, so I can only speak from my experience with nodejs and postgresql. Have you accounted for the fact that you need to be using a bridge network to communicate between docker containers? If you have your sql database in another container you will have to either [use the default bridge network or create your own bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/). I hope this helped in any way.